# What is exactly the notation $f(\left\{x\right\})$ and show $f(\left\{x\right\})=\left\{f\left(x\right)\right\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider the following statement:

If $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$, and we have a family of sets $A_i$ indexed by the index set $I$ then:
$$f( \bigcup\limits_{i∈I}^{} A_{i})=\bigcup\limits_{i∈I}^{}f(A_i)$$

I know the proof but there are some problems in notations:

define $X:=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and let $I=\left\{1,2\right\}$ , $A_1=\left\{1\right\}$ ,  $A_2=\left\{2\right\}$ , then $$f( \bigcup\limits_{i∈I}^{} A_{i})=f( \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2} A_{i})=f(A_1 ∪ A_2 )=f(\left\{1\right\} ∪ \left\{2\right\} )=f(\left\{1,2\right\} )$$

On the other hand $$\bigcup\limits_{i∈I}^{} f(A_{i})=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{2} f(A_{i})= f(A_{1})∪f(A_{2})=f(\left\{1\right\})∪ f(\left\{2\right\})$$

they should be the same, but what is exactly $f(\left\{x\right\})$?, in there any proof that shows me $f(\left\{x\right\})=\left\{f\left(x\right)\right\}$?

Comment: For a set $A$, subset of the domain of a function $f$, people define $f(A)=\{f(x):\ x\in A\}$. In particular $f(\{1\})=\{f(1)\}$. More generally, if $f$ is a binary relation between sets $A$ and $B$, then $f(A)=\{b\in B:\ \exists a\in A,\ f(a)=b\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A\subset X$, then$$f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$$and therefore$$f\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)=\bigl\{f(x)\bigr\}.$$

Comment: let $f(x)$ to be $5$ if $x$ is rational and $3$ for irrationals, then what is $f\left(\left\{2,\log\left(2\right)\right\}\right)$?

Comment: It is $\{5,3\}$.